# LaTeX / Beamer Animation with 2 pictures

Tags: animation, latex, beamer

So basically I need an Animation where it cycles between two pictures i have (lets call them picA and picB). I don't really understand the animategraphics command in LaTeX. How would I implement it or can someone link a description of the method with all its parameters?
Sorry for this fairly idiotic question but i can't seem to find what I want online.

Comment: Do you need to alternate between between the pictures only an infinite amount of times,  say start with A, then B, then back to A, or should they alternate for how long you show the frame?

Comment: It should alternate between A and B for as long as I am on the slide. Doesnt have to look fancy either just alternate between two pictures

Comment: Do you need some code samples?

Comment: Some code would indeed be helpful, then I don't have to start from scratch

Comment: Actually it works now somehow

Comment: That's great to hear!